# phpunit only shows help / usage information, no testresult

Tags: php, windows-7, phpunit, wamp

After some trouble installing phpunit (manually in the end) on wamp and windows 7, it now starts but only shows the usage information you see when you just type in phpunit.

No matter in what directory I am, no matter which directory I point phpunit to, or which file, I only get the usage information.

It does not matter if Wamp is running or not, output stays the same.
The files I use are like these: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/12/16/tutorial-introduction-to-unit-testing-in-php-with-phpunit/

Regards,
Maaike

Comment: BOUNTY: I need answers for getting this to work that don't involve WAMP /XAMPP / PEAR. Like the OP said, I am installing manually. phpunit starts but I never got it to do anything but printing the usage information.

Comment: Can you please display the exact message? If it helps, my invocations look like 'phpunit UnitTest Tests/OaisAipTest.php'.

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit has nothing to do with web server. It is tool which uses PHP-CLI, you call it from the command line.
If PHP-CLI is installed (could be part of WAMP or XAMP), then PHPUnit installation shouldn't be difficult. Easiest is Composer system-wide installation - explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284336/how-to-install-phpunit-using-composer-in-windows-07-64-bit)

If you tried PEAR installation before you can unistall it by `pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit`

To test PHP-CLI just try on command line `php -v`, be sure that php dir is on system path.

To test PHPUnit just try `phpunit --version`

Comment: "To test PHPUnit just try phpunit --version". As I said in my Bounty comments, phpunit --version is the only command that does work for me. So it's not much of a test. Question: If PHP-CLI is *not* installed, would you expect phpunit --version to work?

Comment: Mmmm might have jumped the gun too soon:  `C:\>phpunit --version` ->
`'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` ... BUT: `C:\>phpunit.phar --version` -> 
`PHPUnit 4.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann...` So it only works for me if I add the .phar extension (and as said only ever prints version info)... Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need phpunit.bat and this file needs to be added to system path. Try to check where php.exe sits if this file is there.

Comment: Ah... I never saw that file because the donwload was only a single .phar file. So I did a search for phpunit.bat and found this link: [Installing & setting up PHPUnit manually without PEAR](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/installing-setting-up-phpunit-manually-without-pear/). Awarding you points for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

There can be quite a few problem with phpunit when you don't install it from pear but from hand. Without more detailed output i don't have an idea.

My advice here is to just use pear. I know there are issues with it but please try

```
pear update pear
pear channel-update pear.phpunit.de
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

It works for over 90% of the people i talked to that have troube getting phpunit to run on windows.

If, for some reason, that doesn't solve your problem please comment and I'll try to find another solution. (Maybe include some console output / error messages if you can)

Comment: I decided to use Xampp instead, and there I had no problems at all, though I'll miss wamp's ease in switching php & mySql versions.

Comment: I am still having troubles (because I don't want to use PEAR). Console output is the usage information of phpunit. If there is a way to get more accurate debug info, just let me know how and I will add it.