# How to install PHPUnit using composer in Windows 07 64 bit?

Tags: tdd, phpunit

I have windows 07 64-bit OS and I have downloaded the composer as well as I am running wampserver wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64.exe . I have tried to install PHPUnit using composer but couldn't. I found the installation steps on linux/ mac os but not in windows. Some site suggested to add a dependency on phpunit/phpunit to the php project's composer.json file. But how? I don't know. 
Please help me for the installation of PHPUnit using composer on wampserver(windows 07-64 bit OS) or any alternatives..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do the exact same thing you would do on Linux or OSX.

As from the docs over at: [**`http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer).

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
}
```

and run `php composer.phar install --dev`.

For a system wide install you do:

```
{
    "name": "phpunit",
    "description": "PHPUnit",
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "C:/my/dir"
    }
}
```

and add the directory to your windows `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest to use Pear. Usually you don't install just couple of php classes but also you might need to configure Windows to make phpunit running as tool.

[Try to have a look here](http://blog.loftdigital.com/running-phpunit-tests-in-eclipse-pdt)

Comment: Installing PHPUnit through PEAR is no longer supported. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655136/install-phpunit-on-windows).

Comment: What's the point of commenting something 4 years old? And yes composer is only way in these days.

Comment: For future visitors (newbess who may fall in trap) :-)